# Finding the coefficient for the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have the given problem,

\begin{equation}
    \alpha u_{xx}=u_{tt}
\end{equation}

with conditions:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
    u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0\\
    u(x,0)=x \\
u_t(x,0)=0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Separation of variables gives

\begin{equation}
   u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
    A\sin\frac{kx}{\alpha}\sin\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}\\
    B\cos(\frac{kx}{\alpha})\sin\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}\\
    B\cos(\frac{kx}{\alpha})\cos\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}\\
    B\sin(\frac{kx}{\alpha})\cos\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Having the given IC., we can disregard from the cosine terms for the position function, X(x), which leaves

\begin{equation}
   u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
    A\sin\frac{kx}{\alpha}\sin\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}\\
    B\sin(\frac{kx}{\alpha})\cos\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

We find, using X(x) that:

\begin{equation}
    X(x)= A\sin\frac{kL}{\alpha}=n\pi
\end{equation}

which gives that $k=\frac{n\pi\alpha}{L}$

This gives

\begin{equation}
   u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
    A\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\sin\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}\\
    B\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\cos\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then we discard the term with sine of $t$, since the derivative of the time-function *T(t)* must also be zero at t=0. So we are left with:

\begin{equation}
   u(x,t)= B\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\cos\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}
\end{equation}

expanding to a sum:

\begin{equation}
   u(x,t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty B\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\cos\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}
\end{equation}

But how do I find B?

I tried to use the I.C.  $ u(x,0)=x$ but that didn't work.

Comment: You can't take just a *single* separated solution. You need to make a Fourier sine series out of them, and determine the infinitely many coefficients $B_n$ in order to satisfy the initial condition. Besides, shouldn't there be a second initial condition too, say $u_t(x,0)$ given? (You seem to use $u_t(x,0)=0$ in your argument, don't you?) The PDE is of second order in $t$, so just one initial condition isn't enough to determine the solution uniquely.

Comment: Ok, note this is a hypothetical example I made. I added the second condition you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: OK. But if $u_t(x,0)=1$, then $T'(0)$ isn't zero...

Comment: Yes, then that would not allow removal of the sine forms. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Fourier series you need a different constant $B_n$ in each term, like this:
$$
u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \sin\frac{n\pi x}{L} \cos\frac{\omega t}{\alpha}
.
$$
Then you want to find the constants $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$, etc., so that you achieve $u(x,0) = x$, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}
= x
,
$$
for $0 < x < L$.
And you do this through the usual Fourier trick of multiplying both sides by by $\sin\frac{m \pi x}{L}$ and integrating from $0$ to $L$, using the orthogonality property $\int_0^L \sin\frac{n\pi x}{L} \sin\frac{m \pi x}{L} dx = 0$ for $m \neq n$. Then only the $m$th term on the left-hand side survives, and you get
$$
B_m \int_0^L \sin^2 \frac{m\pi x}{L} dx = \int_0^L x \sin\frac{m\pi x}{L} dx
,
$$
where you can compute the integrals and solve for $B_m$.

Comment: Understood, thank you Hans. This gives $B_n=-\frac{L^2}{n\pi}(-1)^n$

Comment: One comment, I wrote "Then we discard the term with sine of t , since the derivative of the time-function T(t) must also be zero at t=0." but although this selection was correct, it was made on the wrong reasoning. If the derivative of the time function must also be zero at the origin, then we should actually keep the sine term. What is the correct reasoning instead of this, to discard the sine term? Thanks

Comment: You seek a solution in the form of a full Fourier series $\sum A_n (\cdots) + \sum B_n (\cdots)$. When you set $t=0$ the terms with $A_n$ go away, and then you determine $B_n$ from the condition for $u(x,0)$ as above. Then you differentiate the series with respect to $t$, and set $t=0$ again, and now the terms with $B_n$ go away, so that you can determine $A_n$ from the condition for $u_t(x,0)$. And if $u_t(x,0)=0$, then you will get $A_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I wish I could see this so clearly!! Thanks Hans!